# match/lookup/vlookup date error in google sheet

Tags: match, vlookup

match/lookup/vlookup date error in google sheet

I am trying to use match(B1,B1:B100,1) , if B1-B100 is in date format, it always returns NA or the last one , if B1-B100 is number , it's fine .

2021-11-24
2021-11-23
2021-11-22
2021-11-19

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find B1 in B1:B100, the formula return 1 (assuming that dates are sorted correctly because you use the final parameter = 1)

[image]

Comment: I found the reason is my date is in decreasing order , so I should use -1 instead of 1 as parameter . Thanks !